# Shall I omit the second to in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I am learning how to write complex sentences.
(I am writing an email to a friend who can not stop laughing for some reason)

> There are no reasons for you to keep laughing or **to** suspect that I did
>   that funny things on purpose.

Shall I omit the second preposition, to in the above sentence?
If yes, what is this kind of grammar called?

Comment: Either one is fine. Repeating "to" is a little more "correct"/formal, hence less suitable for an email between friends (but still wouldn't be a problem anyway). P.S. I'd say "There's no reason" here; "There are no reasons" sounds like you might have expected multiple reasons to be required for laughing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could omit it, but I find it more natural with the second "to". I think this is because, given the complexity of the sentence it makes it clearer what the *suspect* pairs with.

Incidentally, you have a stray "s" on the end of  "that funny thing". And idiomatically, "There is no reason" is much more natural than "There are no reasons".

Answer (score 1):

I would leave the second *to* in, since the two verb forms "keep laughing" and "suspect" are different. However,

> There are no reasons for you to **laugh or suspect** that I did that funny thing (those funny things) on purpose.

would be fine.